# How add automatically reason of edit (e.g.: added/removed xx characters in body)

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, editing-help

In most edits that I view, in reason of edit I see:
added 21 characters in body
removed 16 characters in body
per example...

My question is if there is any way to add that info (added/removed xx characters in body) automatically in reason when I edit a question or answer?

Comment: You have 5 rep, which means your edits have to be peer reviewed. Even if you *could* automate adding that in some way, you really shouldn't; explain what you've changed and why, and your edits are going to be more well received.

Comment: ok thanks @AnthonyGrist , so as I have no privileges and my edits have to be peer reviewed I have to write what I changed... right? So if you wish you can add a answer and I will accept it... Thanks for the info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is done automatically for users with full editing privileges, but is only offered as part of that privilege because their edits are committed immediately without having to go through peer review.

As a user who does not have full editing privileges, it is on you to explain your changes to the people who will be reviewing edits to make sure that editors know what they are doing.